# Cube maps in libgdx

Tags: android, opengl-es, libgdx

Does anyone know how to get a cubemap to the shader. I cant find any API or tutorials that explain how to do this.

I have just been trying to get it right from things i know from opengl

```
 short []cm=    {       255, 0, 0       };//red



        ByteBuffer bytes = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(3*Short.SIZE).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());      
        ShortBuffer sb = bytes.asShortBuffer();
        sb.get(cm);

       //0 is an argument here since i dont know what else to put tried 1 and 2 aswell
       Gdx.gl.glBindTexture(Gdx.gl20.GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, 0);   

    Gdx.gl20.glTexImage2D(Gdx.gl20.GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_NEGATIVE_X,
            0, Gdx.gl20.GL_RGB, 1, 1, 0, Gdx.gl20.GL_RGB, Gdx.gl20.GL_SHORT, buffer);

    Gdx.gl20.glTexImage2D(Gdx.gl20.GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_NEGATIVE_Y,
            0, Gdx.gl20.GL_RGB, 1, 1, 0, Gdx.gl20.GL_RGB, Gdx.gl20.GL_SHORT, buffer);

    Gdx.gl20.glTexImage2D(Gdx.gl20.GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_NEGATIVE_Z,
            0, Gdx.gl20.GL_RGB, 1, 1, 0, Gdx.gl20.GL_RGB, Gdx.gl20.GL_SHORT, buffer);

    Gdx.gl20.glTexImage2D(Gdx.gl20.GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X,
            0, Gdx.gl20.GL_RGB, 1, 1, 0, Gdx.gl20.GL_RGB, Gdx.gl20.GL_SHORT, buffer);

    Gdx.gl20.glTexImage2D(Gdx.gl20.GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_Y,
            0, Gdx.gl20.GL_RGB, 1, 1, 0, Gdx.gl20.GL_RGB, Gdx.gl20.GL_SHORT, buffer);

    Gdx.gl20.glTexImage2D(Gdx.gl20.GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_Y,
            0, Gdx.gl20.GL_RGB, 1, 1, 0, Gdx.gl20.GL_RGB, Gdx.gl20.GL_SHORT, buffer);
```

this did not work

Comment: If you can wait for a little while, cubemaps will be added soon. See https://twitter.com/xoppa/status/376776662865551360

Comment: You probably want positive Z instead of positive Y twice.

Comment: Thanks @Xoppa. The code i found below in my answer managed to get my program running.

Comment: Cubemap support is added https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/pull/586

Comment: @Xoppa, is it possible to add my `Cubemap` class to the next LibGDX release? It's very convenient and can be used as easy as a texture class. I dug a lot, but still don't know how to use the `native` cubemap. I found only that it is used as an environment

Answer (score 1):

http://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/37311049

I have finally found some source code which uses a cube map.It has no comments though It should be pretty easy to understand if you know opengl-es.

Answer (score 0):

The PowerVR SDK has examples of using cube maps:

http://www.imgtec.com/PowerVR/insider/powervr-insider.asp

Answer (score 0):

I have created a class that makes using a cubemaps very easy.

```
public class Cubemap implements Disposable {

    private final Pixmap[] data = new Pixmap[6];
    private int glHandle;

    public Cubemap(Pixmap positiveX, Pixmap negativeX, Pixmap positiveY, Pixmap negativeY, Pixmap positiveZ, Pixmap negativeZ) {
        set(positiveX, negativeX, positiveY, negativeY, positiveZ, negativeZ);
        reload();
    }

    public Cubemap(FileHandle positiveX, FileHandle negativeX, FileHandle positiveY, FileHandle negativeY, FileHandle positiveZ, FileHandle negativeZ) {
        set(positiveX, negativeX, positiveY, negativeY, positiveZ, negativeZ);
        reload();
    }

    public Cubemap(Pixmap cubemap) {
        set(cubemap);
        reload();
    }

    public Cubemap(Texture texture){
        set(texture);
        reload();
    }

    private void set(Pixmap positiveX, Pixmap negativeX, Pixmap positiveY, Pixmap negativeY, Pixmap positiveZ, Pixmap negativeZ) {
        data[0]=positiveX;
        data[1]=negativeX;

        data[2]=positiveY;
        data[3]=negativeY;

        data[4]=positiveZ;
        data[5]=negativeZ;
    }

    public void set(Texture texture) {
        texture.getTextureData().prepare();
        Pixmap pixmap = texture.getTextureData().consumePixmap();

        data[0]=pixmap;
        data[1]=pixmap;

        data[2]=pixmap;
        data[3]=pixmap;

        data[4]=pixmap;
        data[5]=pixmap;
    }

    private void set(FileHandle positiveX, FileHandle negativeX, FileHandle positiveY, FileHandle negativeY, FileHandle positiveZ, FileHandle negativeZ) {
        set(new Pixmap(positiveX), new Pixmap(negativeX), new Pixmap(positiveY), new Pixmap(negativeY), new Pixmap(positiveZ), new Pixmap(negativeZ));
    }

    //IF ALL SIX SIDES ARE REPRESENTED IN ONE IMAGE
    private void set(Pixmap cubemap) {
        int w = cubemap.getWidth();
        int h = cubemap.getHeight();
        for(int i=0; i<6; i++) data[i] = new Pixmap(w/4, h/3, Pixmap.Format.RGB888);
        for(int x=0; x<w; x++)
            for(int y=0; y<h; y++){
                //-X
                if(x>=0 && x<=w/4 && y>=h/3 && y<=h*2/3) data[1].drawPixel(x, y-h/3, cubemap.getPixel(x, y));
                //+Y
                if(x>=w/4 && x<=w/2 && y>=0 && y<=h/3) data[2].drawPixel(x-w/4, y, cubemap.getPixel(x, y));
                //+Z
                if(x>=w/4 && x<=w/2 && y>=h/3 && y<=h*2/3) data[4].drawPixel(x-w/4, y-h/3, cubemap.getPixel(x, y));
                //-Y
                if(x>=w/4 && x<=w/2 && y>=h*2/3 && y<=h) data[3].drawPixel(x-w/4, y-h*2/3, cubemap.getPixel(x, y));
                //+X
                if(x>=w/2 && x<=w*3/4 && y>=h/3 && y<=h*2/3) data[0].drawPixel(x-w/2, y-h/3, cubemap.getPixel(x, y));
                //-Z
                if(x>=w*3/4 && x<=w && y>=h/3 && y<=h*2/3) data[5].drawPixel(x-w*3/4, y-h/3, cubemap.getPixel(x, y));
            }

        cubemap.dispose();
    }

    public void reload() { 
        glHandle = Gdx.gl20.glGenTexture();    
        Gdx.gl20.glBindTexture(GL20.GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, glHandle);  

        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            Gdx.gl20.glTexImage2D(GL20.GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X + i, 0,
                    GL20.GL_RGB, data[i].getWidth(), data[i].getHeight(), 0,
                    GL20.GL_RGB, GL20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data[i].getPixels());
        }            

        Gdx.gl20.glTexParameterf(GL20.GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL20.GL_LINEAR);
        Gdx.gl20.glTexParameterf(GL20.GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL20.GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
        Gdx.gl20.glTexParameteri(GL20.GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL30.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_R, GL20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        Gdx.gl20.glTexParameteri(GL20.GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        Gdx.gl20.glTexParameteri(GL20.GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

        Gdx.gl20.glGenerateMipmap(GL20.GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP);    
    }

    public void bind(int unit){
        Gdx.gl20.glActiveTexture(GL20.GL_TEXTURE0 + unit);
        Gdx.gl20.glBindTexture(GL20.GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, glHandle);
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose(){
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
            data[i].dispose();

        if (glHandle != 0) {
            Gdx.gl20.glDeleteTexture(glHandle);
            glHandle = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Use it in your shader class:

```
public class YourShader implements com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g3d.Shader {
    ShaderProgram program;
    Cubemap cubemapTex;
    ...

    @Override
    public void init() {
        ...

        cubemapTex = new Cubemap(new Pixmap(Gdx.files.internal("cubemap_image.jpg")));
    }

    @Override
    public void begin(Camera camera, RenderContext context) {
        program.begin();
        ...

        cubemapTex.bind(0);
        program.setUniformi("u_textureCubemap", 0);

        ...
    }
    ...

    @Override
    public void dispose() {               
        if (program != null) {
            program.dispose();
            program = null;
        }

        if(cubemapTex!=null){
            cubemapTex.dispose();
            cubemapTex = null;
        }
        ...
    }
}
```